# STLINK-V3 Mini with STM 32 Chip, Failing to enter SWD mode and timing out

Tags: stm32, st-link

I currently have a STLINK-V3 Mini connected to a board with an STM32 Chip. When running st-flash for the first time I receive the following errors

> 2023-04-17T19:58:38 WARN common.c: NRST is not connected 
> 2023-04-17T19:58:38 ERROR common.c: Soft reset failed: error write to AIRCR
> Failed to enter SWD mode
> Failed to connect to target
> Failed to parse flash type or unrecognized flash type

After this flashing once more gives the following errors

> st-flash 1.7.0-263-g8de2b4d 
> 2023-04-17T20:08:38 ERROR usb.c: GET_VERSION send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT 
> 2023-04-17T20:08:41 ERROR usb.c: GET_CURRENT_MODE send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:08:44 ERROR usb.c: DRIVE_NRST send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:08:47 ERROR usb.c: GET_COM_FREQ send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:08:50 ERROR usb.c: ENTER_SWD send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:08:53 ERROR usb.c: DRIVE_NRST send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:08:56 ERROR usb.c: WRITEDEBUGREG send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:08:59 ERROR usb.c: DRIVE_NRST send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:09:02 ERROR usb.c: WRITEDEBUGREG send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:09:05 ERROR usb.c: READDEBUGREG send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:09:05 WARN common.c: NRST is not connected
> 2023-04-17T20:09:08 ERROR usb.c: WRITEDEBUGREG send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:09:11 ERROR usb.c: WRITEDEBUGREG send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:09:14 ERROR usb.c: WRITEDEBUGREG send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:09:17 ERROR usb.c: READDEBUGREG send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:09:20 ERROR usb.c: WRITEDEBUGREG send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:09:20 ERROR common.c: Soft reset failed: error write to AIRCR
> 2023-04-17T20:09:23 ERROR usb.c: GET_CURRENT_MODE send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> 2023-04-17T20:09:26 ERROR usb.c: ENTER_SWD send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
> Failed to enter SWD mode
> Failed to connect to target
> Failed to parse flash type or unrecognized flash type

The exact st-flash command being ran is st-flash --connect-under-reset --reset write cmake_build/../Motor.bin 0x800000. Commands such as st-info --probe result in the following output

> Failed to enter SWD mode 
> Found 1 stlink programmers
> version:    V3
> serial:     002500115553500B20393256
> flash:      0 (pagesize: 0)
> sram:       0
> chipid:     0x000
> dev-type:   unknown

and st-info --chipid returns the following

> Failed to enter SWD mode
> 0x0000

I have tried flashing to this board with multiple different STLINK-V3 Minis. How do I begin to approach resolving this issue?

Comment: Is it a genuine device from ST or a clone? What signal wires did you connect and how? Especially, do you have VCC connected between programmer and target board, and is the target board powered from where?

Comment: @Justme The STLINK is genuine and is connected to a custom board with a stm32 chip on it. The connections are shown here https://imgur.com/TGlXQtC, https://imgur.com/qOsdoap, https://imgur.com/FJ7Vg35. The target board was powered externally.

Comment: Those diagrams are dificult to follow. They are split and have different net names. Are you sure the target board gives 3.3V MCU supply out to ST-Link? Does MCU have 3.3V? Can you even communicate with target MCU via serial bootloader?